Proving left adjoints preserve left Kan extensions
Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" illustrates the proof of left adjoints preserving left Kan extensions by the following reasoning on pasting diagrams (lemma 6.3.2, proof 2). For a left Kan extension $(\text{Lan}_K F, \eta)$ of $F : C \to E$ along $K : C \to D$ and a functor $L : E \to F$ admitting a right adjoint $R$ (with unit $\iota$ and counit $\nu$):

Given a natural transformation $\alpha : LF \Rightarrow HK$, form the pasted composite with the unit $\iota : 1_E \Rightarrow RL$ displayed below-left.

By the universal property of the left Kan extension $(\text{Lan}_K F, \eta)$, there is a unique factorization through $\eta$ as displayed above-right. Composing each of these natural transformations with the counit $\nu : LR \Rightarrow 1_F$ and applying the triangle identity $\nu L \cdot L \iota = 1_L$,

reveals that $\alpha$ factors through $L \eta$ via the whiskered composite of $\nu H \cdot L \zeta : L\ \text{Lan}_K F \Rightarrow H$ with K.

and I'm not quite sure I follow this reasoning.
Unpacking the pasting diagrams, if I understand correctly, the top left natural transformation is $R \alpha \cdot \iota F : F \Rightarrow RHK$, and the universal property gives us $\zeta$ such that $\zeta K \cdot \eta = R \alpha \cdot \iota F$.
Now, the equality between bottom left and bottom mid diagrams follows from the triangle equality. Or, explicitly: $\alpha = \alpha \cdot \nu LF \cdot L \iota F$ (1). The equality between bottom mid and bottom right ones follows from the top diagrams and by congruence (by post-composing with $\nu HK$). Or, explicitly: $\nu HK \cdot LR \alpha \cdot L \iota F = \nu HK \cdot L \zeta K \cdot L \eta$ (2).
But the problem I'm having is that I cannot immediately apply transitivity: (1)'s right-hand side is different from (2)'s left-hand side, and it only works if the respective compositions in the bottom mid diagram commute — that is, if the composition of the corresponding whiskerings of $\iota$, $\nu$ and $\alpha$ equals the composition of $\iota$, $\alpha$ and $\nu$, which is not at all obvious to me (but I'm not used to reasoning in 2-categories which seems to be implied here after all).
Is this the case? Or am I terribly misunderstanding what's going on in these diagrams?

While I can see why you came up with equation $(1)$, the more natural reading of the bottom left=mid diagrammatic equality is that: $$\alpha=\nu_{HK}\cdot L(R\alpha\cdot \iota_F)$$And the bottom mid=right diagrammatic equality reads that: $$\nu_{HK}\cdot L(R\alpha\cdot\iota_F)=\nu_{HK}\cdot L(\zeta_K\cdot\eta)$$Which is to say: $$\alpha=(\nu_H\cdot L\zeta)_K\cdot L\eta$$Proving existence of a factorisation of $\alpha$ "through" $K$ and $L\eta$. I'm sure Riehl demonstrates uniqueness satisfactorily later.
I say this is more natural, because in your reading (I'll show they're equivalent later) you post-composed by $\alpha$, which isn't explicit in the diagram at all ($\alpha$ is happening before $\nu$, in the flow of things).
I think what would really help is fixing an object $c\in\mathsf{C}$ and explicitly tracking these arrow compositions, ensuring everything type checks.
To get the equality you want, note $L\iota F$ is some map $LF\to LRLF$. $\nu LF$ is the counit $LRLF\to LF$, and if you follow this by $\alpha:LF\to HK$, naturality of $\nu\implies1$ gives $LRLF\to LF\to HK=LRLF\to LRHK\to HK=\nu_{HK}\cdot LR\alpha$, and now $LR\alpha\cdot L\iota F$ is just the thing we had before, $L(R\alpha\cdot \iota F)$. So, appropriately understood, yes, $\alpha\cdot\nu LF\cdot L\iota F=\nu HK\cdot LR\alpha\cdot L\iota F$.
